# Microsoft Dynamics 365 can I use FetchXML to retrieve an entity by guid?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, fetchxml

Given that I have a GUID and an Entity type, can I lookup the Entity using FetchXML?

Why doesn't the following obvious seeming FetchXML work?

```
<fetch>
  <entity name="user_entity" >
    <filter>
      <condition attribute="id" operator="eq" value="cb92c01d-8676-4f41-a5cf-8967cc9de0d9" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure GUID is valid for that entity record. I just quickly tested it in Dev Account entity for result (without any problems) from FetchXML Builder in XrmToolBox.

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" >
  <entity name="account" >
    <filter type="and" >
      <condition attribute="accountid" operator="eq" value="882E3BF1-97F9-E911-A813-000D3A5A1A59" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Also similar to your query:

```
<fetch>
  <entity name="account" >
    <filter>
      <condition attribute="accountid" operator="eq" value="882E3BF1-97F9-E911-A813-000D3A5A1A59" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

GUID is not case-sensitive too.

```
<fetch>
  <entity name="account" >
    <filter>
      <condition attribute="accountid" operator="eq" value="882e3bf1-97f9-e911-a813-000d3a5a1a59" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Comment: The solution is that I had tried to use the attribute="id". I should have used attribute="user_entityid"

Comment: @DavePotts ah I thought you removed your sensitive entity name while posting :)